# Easy way to execute a statement many times in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, push, element

Is there a shorthand way by which I can push n identical elements to an array ?

Can I do this in just one line ?

```
push(@mode_z00,"lib_drx");
push(@mode_z00,"lib_drx");
push(@mode_z00,"lib_drx");
push(@mode_z00,"lib_drx");
push(@mode_z00,"lib_drx");
```

something like 
    push(@mode_z00,5,"lib_drx");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `x` operator to make multiple copies of a value.

```
push(@array, ('foo') x 5);
```

Comment: Almost: push( @array, ( 'foo' ) x 5 );

Comment: That should be `('foo') x 5`. Otherwise you get an array with the one element `'foofoofoofoofoo'`.

Comment: It's useful to think of `()x` as a different operator than plain `x` (at least in list context).

Answer (score 1):

Please do not do this:

```
map( $list[$_] = "lib_drx", (0..4) );
```

thats called using map in void context.

Comment: Why not? It's not like it generates a list anymore.

Comment: ikegami: Because it's obscure. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
push(@mode_z00,'lib_drx') for 1..5;
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to post a different approach that's a bit more flexible with indexing (you could use this to populate a list at a specific range of indices, for example):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                            

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @list;
map($list[$_] = "lib_drx", (0..4));
print Dumper \@list;
```

When run:

```
$ ./mapTest.pl
$VAR1 = [
          'lib_drx',
          'lib_drx',
          'lib_drx',
          'lib_drx',
          'lib_drx'
        ];
```

The use of `push()` seems faster for very large populations, but `map()` lets you specify arbitrary start and stop indices:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                            

use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark;

my $startTime = new Benchmark();

my $startIndex = 0;
my $stopIndex = (1000000 - 1);
my @list;
map($list[$_] = "lib_drx", ($startIndex..$stopIndex));

my $stopTime = new Benchmark();

print STDOUT "runtime: ".timestr(timediff($stopTime, $startTime), 'all')." sec\n";
```

For a million additions, here is the runtime of the `map()` approach:

```
runtime:  1 wallclock secs ( 0.36 usr  0.10 sys +  0.00 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.46 CPU) sec
```

And for the `push()` approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                            

use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark;

my $startTime = new Benchmark();

my $count = 1000000;
my @list;
push(@list, ('lib_drx') x $count);

my $stopTime = new Benchmark();

print STDOUT "runtime: ".timestr(timediff($stopTime, $startTime), 'all')." sec\n";
```

The runtime for `push()` is a little less than half that of the `map()` runtime:

```
runtime:  1 wallclock secs ( 0.18 usr  0.07 sys +  0.00 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.25 CPU) sec
```

Comment: That's a lot of energy to describe a bad solution.  If you really want to go that direction, an inline `for` loop is usually more readable.

Comment: `map` in void context is almost always better written in statement modifier form with a `for` loop: `$list[$_] = 'lib_drx' for $start .. $stop;`.  The exception being if the `map` requires several statements (`;`) and it is important for those statements to appear before the data they act upon (a large `qw/list of terms not needed elsewhere/` for example).  In that case, either `do {;;;} for ...;` or `map {;;;} ...;` depending on your preference.